# Magento 2 Error while canceling the order

Tags: magento2, orders, plugin, sales-rule

**I'm facing the below error while canceling the order**

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magentodb`.`salesrule_customer`, CONSTRAINT `SALESRULE_CUSTOMER_RULE_ID_SALESRULE_RULE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`rule_id`) REFERENCES `salesrule` (`rule_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO `salesrule_customer` () VALUES ()
```

**I found this solution https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/16779 According to this reference I made direct changes in `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Coupon/Usage/Processor.php` file of this `updateCustomerRuleUsages()` then an error is gone**

**I tried the same thing by overriding the class `Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon\Usage\Processor` it shows the error**

`You have not canceled the item.`

> Myvendor\Mymodule\Model\Coupon\Usage\Processor.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Myvendor\Mymodule\Model\Coupon\Usage;

use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Coupon\Usage;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\CustomerFactory;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory;

/**
 * Processor to update coupon usage
 */
class Processor extends \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon\Usage\Processor
{
    /**
     * @var RuleFactory
     */
    private $ruleFactory;

    /**
     * @var RuleFactory
     */
    private $ruleCustomerFactory;

    /**
     * @var Coupon
     */
    private $coupon;

    /**
     * @var Usage
     */
    private $couponUsage;

    /**
     * @param RuleFactory $ruleFactory
     * @param CustomerFactory $ruleCustomerFactory
     * @param Coupon $coupon
     * @param Usage $couponUsage
     */
    public function __construct(
        RuleFactory $ruleFactory,
        CustomerFactory $ruleCustomerFactory,
        Coupon $coupon,
        Usage $couponUsage
    ) {
        $this->ruleFactory = $ruleFactory;
        $this->ruleCustomerFactory = $ruleCustomerFactory;
        $this->coupon = $coupon;
        $this->couponUsage = $couponUsage;
        parent::__construct($ruleFactory,$ruleCustomerFactory, $coupon, $couponUsage);
    }

    /**
     * Update the number of rule usages per customer
     *
     * @param bool $isIncrement
     * @param int $ruleId
     * @param int $customerId
     */
    private function updateCustomerRuleUsages(bool $increment, int $ruleId, int $customerId)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Customer $ruleCustomer */
        $ruleCustomer = $this->ruleCustomerFactory->create();
        $ruleCustomer->loadByCustomerRule($customerId, $ruleId);
        
        if ($ruleCustomer->getId()) {
            if ($increment || $ruleCustomer->getTimesUsed() > 0) {
                $ruleCustomer->setTimesUsed($ruleCustomer->getTimesUsed() + ($increment ? 1 : -1));
                $ruleCustomer->save(); //ADD SAVE METHOD WITHIN THE CONDITION
            }
        } elseif ($increment) {
            $ruleCustomer->setCustomerId($customerId)->setRuleId($ruleId)->setTimesUsed(1);
            $ruleCustomer->save(); //ADD SAVE METHOD WITHIN THE CONDITION
        }
        //$ruleCustomer->save(); //REMOVE SAVE METHOD
    }
}
```

> In that reference, there is a comment quoting

**"I just made the change in the base code(I know, bad), but you could potentially use a plugin to jump into the $ruleCustomer->save() and prevent the save from happening. This is a bit clunky though because save() is on the AbstractModel class used by all kinds of things."**

**I'm wondering if we can write a plugin for `$ruleCustomer->save()`. Please Let me know if anyone has any ideas.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally, I figured it out by myself. Instead of overriding this function `updateCustomerRuleUsages` I debugged found out that it's getting called from `public function process(UpdateInfo $updateInfo): void`**

**So I added the code of `updateCustomerRuleUsages` instead of calling and it works for me. Below are the file changes.**

> Myvendor/MyModule/CustomApis/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon\Usage\Processor" type="Myvendor\MyModule\Model\Coupon\Usage\Processor"/>
</config>
```

> Myvendor/MyModule/Model/Coupon/Usage/Processor.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Myvendor\MyModule\Model\Coupon\Usage;

use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Coupon\Usage;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\CustomerFactory;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon\Usage\UpdateInfo;

/**
 * Processor to update coupon usage
 */
class Processor extends \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon\Usage\Processor
{
    /**
     * @var RuleFactory
     */
    private $ruleFactory;

    /**
     * @var RuleFactory
     */
    private $ruleCustomerFactory;

    /**
     * @var Coupon
     */
    private $coupon;

    /**
     * @var Usage
     */
    private $couponUsage;

    /**
     * @param RuleFactory $ruleFactory
     * @param CustomerFactory $ruleCustomerFactory
     * @param Coupon $coupon
     * @param Usage $couponUsage
     */
    public function __construct(
        RuleFactory $ruleFactory,
        CustomerFactory $ruleCustomerFactory,
        Coupon $coupon,
        Usage $couponUsage
    ) {
        $this->ruleFactory = $ruleFactory;
        $this->ruleCustomerFactory = $ruleCustomerFactory;
        $this->coupon = $coupon;
        $this->couponUsage = $couponUsage;
        parent::__construct($ruleFactory,$ruleCustomerFactory, $coupon, $couponUsage);
    }

    /**
     * Update coupon usage
     *
     * @param UpdateInfo $updateInfo
     */
    public function process(UpdateInfo $updateInfo): void
    {
        if (empty($updateInfo->getAppliedRuleIds())) {
            return;
        }

        if (!empty($updateInfo->getCouponCode())) {
            $this->updateCouponUsages($updateInfo);
        }
        $isIncrement = $updateInfo->isIncrement();
        $customerId = $updateInfo->getCustomerId();
        // use each rule (and apply to customer, if applicable)
        foreach (array_unique($updateInfo->getAppliedRuleIds()) as $ruleId) {
            if (!(int)$ruleId) {
                continue;
            }
            $this->updateRuleUsages($isIncrement, (int)$ruleId);
            if ($customerId) {
                // $this->updateCustomerRuleUsages($isIncrement, (int)$ruleId, $customerId);
                /** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Customer $ruleCustomer */
                $ruleCustomer = $this->ruleCustomerFactory->create();
                $ruleCustomer->loadByCustomerRule($customerId, $ruleId);
                
                if ($ruleCustomer->getId()) {
                    if ($isIncrement || $ruleCustomer->getTimesUsed() > 0) {
                        $ruleCustomer->setTimesUsed($ruleCustomer->getTimesUsed() + ($isIncrement ? 1 : -1));
                        $ruleCustomer->save(); //ADD SAVE METHOD WITHIN THE CONDITION
                    }
                } elseif ($isIncrement) {
                    $ruleCustomer->setCustomerId($customerId)->setRuleId($ruleId)->setTimesUsed(1);
                    $ruleCustomer->save(); //ADD SAVE METHOD WITHIN THE CONDITION
                }
                //$ruleCustomer->save(); //REMOVE SAVE METHOD
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Hope it helps.**

Comment: On spot!!! thank you!!

Comment: I'm glad that you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

By removing the `save` method call, you might have eliminated part of the functionality. After all, cart price rules include the *Uses per Customer* setting. If a customer uses a rule and the order is subsequently canceled, the available uses for that customer should not be reduced. If they were, `updateCustomerRuleUsages` is where they would be restored.

This appears to be a Magento bug. Starting from Magento 2.4.5, they wrapped the call like this:

```
if ($ruleCustomer->hasData()) {
    $ruleCustomer->save();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just to let you know I didn't eliminate the functionality I'm just using the code of this `updateCustomerRuleUsages` instead of calling it.